# Selenium+Java. click or sendKeys not working with element received via cycle

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to click received element but can't for unknown reasons.
Cycle is:

```
public WebElement element(String title) {
        for (WebElement el : list) {
            if (el.getText().equals(title)) {
                return el;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and click is just

```
click(element("title"));
```

...but when I specify element directly:

```
click(...findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id']//span[position ()>1]//*[text()[contains(.,'title')]]"));
```

everything working perfectly.

May metter that requested element is situated in previously opened div.
Thank you.

Comment: what is exception here?

Comment: There is no errors except error 'Unable to locate element. But its all about another next method.

Comment: Where is the code for locating the element?

Comment: @Guy '@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='id']//span[position ()>1]")
    List<WebElement> list;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this by adding /a to elements xpath:

```
public WebElement element(String title) {
    for (WebElement el : list) {
        if (el.getText().equals(title)) {
            return el**.findElement(By.xpath("a")**;
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

it's strange that xpath w/o "a" works excelent directly and doesnt via for cycle...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this if statement inside the foreach loop returns null and exits. That exaplains why when value passed directly, it works. 
In order to be sure maybe you need to debug it. By seeing this code, this is the only hint I can give you ...

Comment: I've thougt same way and have checked it out with debug - right element receiving.